# Img src changes but not the actual image

Tags: jquery, image, events, canvas, fabricjs

I'm changing image by clicking on a button. I can see in the src code that the image is changed, but the actual image isn't changing in the browser. How come, and how to solve it?

```
// AvatarGenerator.eyes = 1;

moveRightBtn.on('click', function(){
    var newImage = 'eyes' + (AvatarGenerator.eyes + 1) + '.png';

    $('#eyesImg').attr('src','img/' + newImage);
});
```

EDIT: I created a jsFiddle that actually works, but the thing is that I'm using *fabric.js* (a canvas framework), which may be the reason for it's not working even thought I can't understand why. :(

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Any console errors pertaining to fabric.js?

Comment: @tymeJV: No console errors at all.

Comment: Are you able to remove fabric.js from your page and confirm it works without the script?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal test case in a fiddle that uses fabric.js? Here's an empty fiddle with fabric.js and jQuery imported already: http://jsfiddle.net/GV5KY/1/

Comment: Do really just have an `<img>` that fails to load a new image, or are you actually trying to *use* the new image *on a canvas* where it fails to appear/change? That's something you should include in your example code.

Comment: I tried to with fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GV5KY/9/), but didn't manage to show the image by some strange reason. However, you can see the code.

Comment: What about instead of modifying the src of the current `img`, you add a new one, remove the current then change id of the new to the old? Like this: `var newImg = $('<img />',{id:'eyesImg2', src:'img/' + newImage}); $('#eyesImg').after(newImg).remove();$('#eyesImg2').attr('id','eyesImg');`

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Rather than adding and removing, use the handy `replaceWith` jQuery function to replace an element. Makes your suggestion a bit more readable and no need to make the id-stuff overcomplicated.

Comment: @RenéWolferink Awesome. Never had used that one. Thanks for the suggestion. so yeah `$('#eyesImg').replaceWith('<img id="eyesImg" src="img/' + newImage+'" />');` lot smaller :P For more info, [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Comment: Strange, tried to replace the image but it's the same thing. The src code changes but nothing is changed in the browser. Can it be because it's inside canvas tags?

Comment: @holyredbeard Sorry, apparently the fabric.js import didn't get saved properly in the fiddle. Here is a working version with the recommendations from my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/GV5KY/10/ (except it doesn't have a second image to switch to, since the current path is a 404.)

Answer (score 2):

Your fabric.js code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    angle: 30,
    opacity: 0.85
});

canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

"stamps" a *visual copy* of the image onto the canvas. The canvas doesn't hold any kind of reference of the original image element, because a canvas is just a dumb grid of pixels. Canvases don't know anything *about* what they represent, they just hold pixel data.

Thus, when the original image element that was used for the "stamp" changes, there's no reason for the "imprint" pixels on the canvas to change. Instead, you need to re-run your fabric.js code to stamp new pixels onto the canvas.